# showing categories wordpress in google result , HOW?

Tags: wordpress

how are you?

this is my website: http://rehlat-world.com

when I search in google : site:rehlat-world.com

The result only "POSTS , PAGES , TAGS"

I need to include categories but I can't

this is example for category : http://rehlat-world.com/country/indonesia

=======================

The source of category page "  " also it is include in sitemaps.xml http://rehlat-world.com/sitemap.xml

Please Help me how can include it.

Note I'm using this plugins (All in One SEO Pack و Google XML Sitemaps , WP Super Cache)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can help you with your issue. This is an easy error to make and thankfully just as easy to fix.

If you take a look at the source code of your category pages (right click anywhere on page, select link to source code).

On line 9 you will see

```
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
```

This is perfectly fine but then if you scroll down to lines 74 - 80, you will see All in One Seo plugin has also added its metatags,

```
<!-- All in One SEO Pack 1.6.13.2 by Michael Torbert of Semper Fi Web Design[418,446] -->  <meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow"/>  <link rel="canonical" href="http://rehlat-world.com/country/indonesia"/>  <!-- /all in one seo pack -->
```

So you can see the repeated "robots" meta tag specifying "noindex". Simply go to into your All In One Seo plugin settings and disable the option to add robots meta tags to categories.
Obviously the first meta tag is all you need.

This will do the job and cats will be indexed in no time.

I will also add a suggestion that will help your site in the future by making it more appealing to your visitors and the search engines. I looked in your sitemap and noticed your permalinks are extremely ugly due to the Arabic text being used, which inturn cant be recognized by wordpress or the browsers because you still have wordpress set in English. You should really change your wordpress language config to Arabic.

The very first line in your source file says `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

Strict//EN tells your browser the website is set in the English language and thats how the internet browsers should read the website. You should be able to fix this by adding  in the header.php file of your theme, above the  tag. I think this should work but im not 100% sure and may be wrong.

You also edit your wp-config.php file and find `define ('WPLANG', '');`, change that to define ('WPLANG', 'ar');. I have very little experiance with this so it would be wise to read http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress#WordPress_Localization_Repository
could also save you time to do it with a plugin like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gtranslate/

If you are already well aware of this and its not causing any issues with your rankings, disregard what I said.

Good luck

Aaron

Comment: wow You ara right. I'don't know how can thank. Thank a lot Mr Aaron. It is very useful advice. Thank you very very much ^_^ ..